# Why is Ghost absent from this fight? Where is he?

Tags: game-of-thrones

After seeing episode 9 of season 6 I really was wondering where Ghost, the direwolf was.

It would seem logical that he would be around I think but I believe I haven't seen him

> Since Jon resurrected

Comment: He probably went sailing with Gendry...

Comment: Probably left out because they work with real dogs and the battle of the bastards was a huge scene with a lot of people and horses. Having to work with a dog to create some epic scene in this battle would have taken a lot more work and it already took them 25 days to shoot that battle alone.

Comment: CGI costs money.

Comment: It seems like the producers are keen to kill off the wolves, and not show them often, so it feels like they are thinking they are not worth the trouble.

Comment: Same reason they killed the Giant, he was getting too expensive

Comment: There is a plausible answer on Movies and TV SE for this, though it's obviously unconfirmed.   http://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/55717/where-was-ghost-during-the-battle-of-the-bastards

Comment: @Aegon how big is that boat? Gendry, Ghost, Nymeria, and the Sand Snakes all rowing together. Haha.

Comment: He's busy keeping Summer safe.

Comment: @Broklynite Summer is dead. The only remaining direwolves are Ghost and Nymeria

Comment: Of course Summer is dead- Winter is Coming.

Comment: Given the luck of the direwolves so far this season, probably a judicious move by Jon to protect his companion from the screen writers.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Out-of-universe explanation:

It is too expensive to shot scenes with direwolves. HBO is having problems with money. It's the main reason why there was no Ghost in that battle

This was confirmed by [Miguel Sapochnik, director of the episode](http://uk.businessinsider.com/game-of-thrones-director-why-ghost-wasnt-in-battle-of-the-bastards-2016-6):

> "[Ghost] was in there in spades originally, but it's also an
>   incredibly time consuming and expensive character to bring to life,"
>   the episode's director Miguel Sapochnik told Business Insider on
>   Monday. "Ultimately **we had to choose between Wun-Wun and the direwolf,
>   so the dog bit the dust**."

Comment: +1 beat me to it. Just saw the article on LadBible and got the link to business insider from there. Came here in a hurry "Oh oh oh I got the answer" and there it was haha.

Comment: How is HBO having problems with money? I pay them like $15 per month just to watch this show.

Comment: @Andrew you can ask a question about it! But I'm not sure if that question would be on-topic. And it could be opinion-based

Answer (score -1):

He was left at the Watch Tower with Jon's BFF to watch over them. Jon, Sansa & Davos were embarking on a journey to recruit men, so he had to stay behind.

Comment: Who's Jon's BFF? Mel?

Comment: Edd, presumably. His name isn't mentioned very often in the show. This sounds plausible actually, I don't remember seeing Ghost being released from the kennels.